# Plotly: is there a way to save the data of a clicked point in a list?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a 2D plotly graph with a hover feature. When you hover over each point, the label (e.g. 'image 2, cluster 1') associated with that point appears. I'd like for label to be appended onto an existing list if I were to click on the point (rather than just hover over it). The reason why is that I'd later like to use the data of this point to perform another task. Is there an example online that demonstrates how to do this-- have looked through the documentation but haven't found something for this yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hoverData` that is available to you by default, with some sample data, is this:

```
{
  "points": [
    {
      "curveNumber": 1,
      "pointNumber": 7,
      "pointIndex": 7,
      "x": 1987,
      "y": 74.32,
      "bbox": {
        "x0": 420.25,
        "x1": 426.25,
        "y0": 256,
        "y1": 262
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean by `'label'`, so I can only assume that it would be the name of a trace or something similar, like in this example from the Plotly docs:

[image]

But as you can see, that's not readily available in the `hoverData` dict. This means that you'll have to use this information to reference your figure structure as well, so that you end up with something like this:

```
[['New Zealand', 2002, 79.11]]
```

And that's not a problem as long as you're willing to use Plotly Dash. I've made a complete setup for you that should meet your requirements. In the app in the image below you'll find a figure along with two output fields for strings. The first field shows the info from that last point you've clicked in the figure. On every click, a new element is added to a list named `store`. The last fields shows the complete information from the same click.

The answer to your question is, yes, there is a way to save the data of a clicked point in a list. And one way to do so is through the following callback that uses clickdata to reference your figure object, store those references in a list, and append new elements every time you click a new element.

#### App

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import json
from textwrap import dedent as d
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import dash
from dash import dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

# app info
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
styles = {
    'pre': {
        'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'overflowX': 'scroll'
    }
}

# data
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")

# plotly figure
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="country", title="No label selected")
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines")

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='figure1',
        figure=fig,
    ),

    html.Div(className
             ='row', children=[
        html.Div([
            dcc.Markdown(d("""Hoverdata using figure references""")),
            html.Pre(id='hoverdata2', style=styles['pre']),
        ], className='three columns'),
                 
                     html.Div([
            dcc.Markdown(d("""
              
              Full hoverdata
            """)),
            html.Pre(id='hoverdata1', style=styles['pre']),
        ], className='three columns')   
    ]),
    
])

# container for clicked points in callbacks
store = []

@app.callback(
    Output('figure1', 'figure'),
    Output('hoverdata1', 'children'),
    Output('hoverdata2', 'children'),
    [Input('figure1', 'clickData')])
def display_hover_data(hoverData):
    
    if hoverData is not None:
        traceref = hoverData['points'][0]['curveNumber']
        pointref = hoverData['points'][0]['pointNumber']
        store.append([fig.data[traceref]['name'],
                      fig.data[traceref]['x'][pointref],
                     fig.data[traceref]['y'][pointref]])
        fig.update_layout(title = 'Last label was ' + fig.data[traceref]['name'])
        return fig, json.dumps(hoverData, indent=2), str(store)
    else:
        return fig, 'None selected', 'None selected'

app.run_server(mode='external', port = 7077, dev_tools_ui=True,
          dev_tools_hot_reload =True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: you are an angel. thank you so much!

Comment: Vestland, quick question: so in my original code, I had it so that the images associated with each point would be displayed if I hovered over the point. However, I'm not sure how to incorporate this feature into your code. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @SofiaRValdez Thank you for accepting my answer! Regarding your new question, I'm not sure if it would work, and I'm not *quite* sure what you're aiming to do. But if you would take the time to put togetether a repdroducible example with some sample data in a new question, I'm sure we could figure something out. If you're not sure how to write up a completely reproducible question, I'd be happy to assist you with that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use callbacks to perform this type of action (register `on_click()`).  Have defined `clicked` as a list of clicked points.   Demonstrated how this can be achieved with **ipwidgets** or **dash**

#### ipwidgets

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import ipywidgets as widgets
from pathlib import Path
import json

x = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=50)
y = np.sin(x)
clicked = []

# construct figure that has holders for points, interpolated line and final lines
fig = go.FigureWidget(
    [
        go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode="markers", name="base_points"),
    ]
)
fig.update_layout(template="simple_white")

out = widgets.Output(layout={"border": "1px solid black"})
out.append_stdout("Output appended with append_stdout\n")

# create our callback function
@out.capture()
def base_click(trace, points, selector):
    global clicked
    clicked.append(points.__dict__)

fig.data[0].on_click(base_click)

widgets.HBox([fig, out])
```

#### dash

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import numpy as np
import json

clicked = []

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [
        dash.dcc.Graph(
            id="fig",
            figure=go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode="markers", name="base_points")),
        ),
        dash.html.Div(id="debug"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("debug", "children"),
    Input("fig", "clickData"),
)
def point_clicked(clickData):
    global clicked
    clicked.append(clickData)

    return json.dumps(clickData)

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```